# Sorting and filtering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code block, I want to perform sorting and filtering according to the panels I have defined on top. User can select sorting criteria and order to sort the data. User can select the criteria and related values to get the filtered results. Note: first I want to pull dynamic drop down according to the selected criteria while filtering.

```
class StudentRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const student = this.props.student;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{student.ID}</td>
        <td>{student.Name}</td>
        <td>{student.Age}</td>
        <td>{student.Major}</td>
        <td>{student.College}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class DropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {criteria: 'id', order: 'ascending'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your cretiria is: ' + this.state.criteria + ' Order is: ' + this.state.order);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

        <label>
          Cretiria to sort:
          <select value={this.state.criteria} name="criteria" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="id">ID    </option>
            <option value="name">Name  </option>
            <option value="age">Age   </option>
            <option value="major">Major </option>
            <option value="college">College</option>
          </select>
        </label>

        <label>
          Order of sorting:
          <select value={this.state.order} name="order" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="ascending">Ascending</option>
            <option value="descending">Descending</option>
          </select>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}


class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {criteria: 'id', value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your cretiria is: ' + this.state.criteria + ' Value is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

        <label>
          Cretiria to filter:
          <select value={this.state.criteria} name="criteria" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="id">ID    </option>
            <option value="name">Name  </option>
            <option value="age">Age   </option>
            <option value="major">Major </option>
            <option value="college">College</option>
          </select>
        </label>

        <label>
          Value to filer:
          <select value={this.state.value} name="value" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            // Need dynamic values here
          </select>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: too much code man narrow down the problem, if its just an issue of sorting show what you need sorted and where exactly.

Comment: Sorting on data, according to the drop down selection

Comment: need you to narrow it down theres too much code

Comment: StudentTable using StudentRow to populate rows in table. Now I need sorting according to DropDown and Filter according to Filter DropDown

Answer (score 1):

`const filtereData = data.filter(item => item.value === valuetofilter);`

```
  <label>
    Value to filer:
    <select value={this.state.value} name="value" onChange={this.handleChange}>
      {filteredData.map(item => <option value={item.value}> {item.value} </option>}
    </select>
  </label>
```

replace item.value with the value from the data you want to use to compare. Then valuetofilter is the value from the state that the user queried. If it matches a new option element will be returned into the select.